# Log File not getting created using log4j2

Tags: logging, log4j, log4j2

```
status = trace
name= properties_configuration

#Make sure to change log file path as per your need
property.filename = C:\\Users\\xxxxx\\IdeaProjects\\Logs\\rd.log
 
filters = threshold
 
filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
filter.threshold.level = debug
 
appenders = rolling
 
appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = RollingFile
appender.rolling.fileName = ${filename}
appender.rolling.filePattern = debug-backup-%d{MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss}-%i.log.gz
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size=10MB
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy


appender.rolling.strategy.max = 20
logger.rolling.name = com.rightdata.web
loggers = rolling
logger.rolling.level = debug
logger.rolling.additivity = false
logger.rolling.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile


# Classes in this package or sub packages will use ConsoleAppender and RollingFileAppender for logging
logger.appLogger.name = com.rightdata.web
logger.appLogger.level = debug
logger.appLogger.additivity = false
logger.appLogger.appenderRef.rolling.ref = appLoggerAppender
logger.appLogger.appenderRef.console.ref = consoleLoggerAppender
rootLogger.level = info
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = consoleLoggerAppender
```

Not able to create log file under Logs folder, Any settings to be changed? When i restart middleware service log file is not created.I want to create Log files with timestamp How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You have status=trace set. If you aren't seeing any output from that on the console then log4j2 isn't being used. If you are seeing the output from that you should provide it as it almost certainly would be telling you that it is not allowed to have 2 loggers with the same name. You need to put both appender references under a single logger.